# How to download all files in an Azure Container Directory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an aspnet app which i upload files to the azure blobs. I know that azure don't create structural paths in the containers, just blobs, but you can emulate directories putting a "/" on the uri.

i.e
I'd upload a list of files and my uri is like this

http://myaccount.windowsazure.blob.net/MyProtocolID-01/MyDocumentID-01/FileName01.jpg
http://myaccount.windowsazure.blob.net/MyProtocolID-01/MyDocumentID-01/FileName02.jpg
http://myaccount.windowsazure.blob.net/MyProtocolID-01/MyDocumentID-01/FileName03.jpg

My download method:

```
 public RemoteFile Download(DownloadRequest request)
    {
        var fileFinal = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",request.IDProtocol ,request.IDDocument, request.FileName);

        var blobBlock = InitializeDownload(fileFinal);

        if (!blobBlock.Exists())
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Error");
        }

        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        blobBlock.DownloadToStream(stream);

        return File(request.FileName)
    }

 private CloudBlob InitializeDownload(string uri)
    {
        var blobBlock = _blobClient.GetBlobReference(uri);
        return blobBlock;
    }
```

This way, i'm getting just one file. But i need to see and download all files inside http://myaccount.windowsazure.blob.net/MyProtocolID-01/MyDocumentID-01/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding more details. You will need to use one of the listing APIs provided by the client library:  CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs(), CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmented(), and CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync() (and various overloads.). You can specify the directory prefix, and the service will only enumerate blobs matching the prefix.  You can then download each blob.  You may also want to look at the ‘useFlatBlobListing’ argument, depending on your scenario.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs.aspx

In addition AzCopy (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx) also supports this scenario of downloading all blobs in a given directory path.

Answer (score 1):

Since each blob is a separate web resource, function above will download only one file. One thing you could do is list all blobs using the logic you are using and then download those blobs on your server first, zip them and the return that zip file to your end user.

Answer (score 1):

Use AzCopy functionalities, now, it has a lot of supports.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10